# why the div was not in its parent

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

    div {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 50px 20%;
    }

    * {
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    }

    div * {
        width: 100%;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 48px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    p.grey {
        color: grey;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    p#ending {
        text-align: center;
    }

    ul {
        border-top: 3px solid black;
        border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    li {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    div#images {
        border: 1px solid black;

    }

    div#images>img {
        width: 30%;

        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);

        filter: grayscale(100%);

        filter: gray;
    }

    li:hover, li:active {
        color: red;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p class="grey">THE</p>
    <h1>ANALOG</h1>
    <p class="grey">SPECIALISTS</p>
    <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>FOR SALE</li>
        <li>REPAIRES</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="http://www.99-taobao.com/uploads/151109/1-    151109142014X3.jpg" alt="pic1">
        <img src="http://www.99-taobao.com/uploads/151109/1-151109142014X3.jpg" alt="pic2">
        <img src="http://www.99-taobao.com/uploads/151109/1-151109142014X3.jpg" alt="pic3">
    </div>
    <p id="ending">We specialise in the sales and repair of classic keyboards, in particular
    the Fender Rhodes, Wurlitzer EP200, and Hohner Clavinet.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess it's a stupid problem, but I was writing this piece of html and css code, and I wanted to center the div#image, now it doesn't work, but if I add margin-left: 5% to div#image, it will work. Does anyone know why it's like that?

The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS7Nb.png).

After I added the margin-left, it worked out fine like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8kAy.png).

Comment: try: margin: 0 auto; on #images css block. your all divs forced to 60% width. So, you have a witdh, you can center that block with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An accepted CSS technique to centre a given div on a page is to use:

```
    #images {
    margin:0 auto
}
```

The auto just tells the browser to split up the available space evenly between the left and right side of the element. By available space, it means any unoccupied horizontal space between the left and right edges of the parent container.

You should also be using more structural divs to control layout on your page, for example:

```
 <div id="ThisHeader">

    <p class="grey">THE</p>
      <h1>ANALOG</h1>
         <p class="grey">SPECIALISTS</p>

      <div id="MenuMain">
    <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>FOR SALE</li>
        <li>REPAIRES</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>

  </div> <!-- Close Menu Main -->

</div> <!-- Close header -->
```

For header, apply a width of 100%:

```
        #ThisHeader {
       width: 100%;
          }
```

This will prevent the items in the header messing up the layout of other items on the page.  If you have a 100% width header, items underneath that may be floated cannot get messed up by it.

--

A summary would be you need to learn how to create a nice CSS page layout using divs like header, mainbody and footer, to control where the elements on your page will appear.  I would research some basic CSS layout techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You put a margin on the div and also made all the contents of that div `width:100%`. This causes the div to go off center and then expand to the right.

If you remove `div * { width:100%; }` you'll see what I mean.

What you probably wanted to do is let your images float to the left, and put an `overflow:auto;` onto the div to contain all the images.